# Why does fragmentation of the managed heap affect the success of unmanaged heap allocation requests?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, unmanaged-memory

I have not been able to find a satisfactory explanation as to why calling GC.Collect before a large *unmanaged* allocation (in my case, before creating a large (~250Mb) DirectX resource) prevents an out-of-memory exception.  Why does a compaction of the managed heap allow an unmanaged allocation?

How does a .Net process share its address space between the managed and unmanaged heaps?

My best guess is the .Net process maintains a moveable boundary between the two types of heap and GC.Collect allows that boundary to move in favour of a larger unmanaged heap.  Something like this:

- (M)anaged allocations
- (U)nmanaged allocations
- (F)ree memory
- Process address space 0-9

***Scenario #1 – no GC.Collect***

About to make unmanaged allocation of 3 blocks, managed heap fragmented:

```
0123456789
MMFFMFFMFU
```

"High-water mark" of managed heap at 7

Allocate 3 unmanaged blocks – **fails!**
Note high-water mark of managed heap leaves no space for the unmanaged allocation.

***Scenario #2 – with GC.Collect***

About to make unmanaged allocation of 3 blocks, managed heap fragmented

```
0123456789
MMFFMFFMFU
```

"High water mark" of managed heap at 7

Call GC.Collect

```
0123456789
MMMMFFFFFU
```

"High water mark" of managed heap at 3

Allocate 3 unmanaged blocks – **succeeds!**

```
0123456789
MMMMFFUUUU
```

Is this how it works?

Comment: *The garbage collector also reserves segments as needed, and releases segments back to the operating system* - from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx). So yes, freeing managed memory will free some portion of unmanaged memory. Not necessarily as you show it in #2 scenario, as it may stay fragmented. But you definitely get more chances to allocate big block successfully after `GC.Collect`.

Comment: You can get lucky this way, no guarantee whatsoever and high odds that it will still fail on another machine or when you make seemingly innocent looking changes to your program.  If you want a reasonable guarantee that the OS memory manager can find a 250 MB hole then you have to do it early at program startup.  The sooner the better.  And of course the real fix, there are no good reasons left to still run programs in 32-bit mode today.